# Extract data from a form in CURL

Tags: php, mysql, curl

can someone please guide me through how I could extract content out of the form below using DOMDocument(); . I was able to extract all the links i.e ../index.html,descriptions/page001 e.t.c and save extracted data into mysql database but am stuck on how to get the content i.e Accounting,Adult Continuing Education e.t.c and save the information into database.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD></HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM ACTION="#">
<SELECT ONCHANGE="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)" NAME="menu1"> 
<OPTION VALUE="../index.html" SELECTED="SELECTED"></OPTION> 
<OPTION VALUE="descriptions/page001.html">Accounting</OPTION> 
<OPTION VALUE="descriptions/page122.html">Adult Continuing Education</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="descriptions/page115.html">Energy Engineering</OPTION> 
</SELECT>
</P></FORM> 
</BODY>
</HTML>


MY CURL SCRIPT
// parse the html into a DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

// grab all on the page
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);


// GET AND LOOP THROUGH LINKS
$values = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//option");
for ($cnt = 0; $cnt < $values->length; $cnt++) {
$value = $values->item($cnt);
$url = $value->getAttribute('value');
    //store extracted links and links source into the database function
storeLink($url,$target_url);
echo "Link stored: $url";
}
```

Any help would be appreciated please. Thanks.

Comment: could you explain "stuck on how to get the content". Its not clear.

Comment: What I mean by stuck on it is I cant seems to be able to extract data like Accounting,Adult Continuing Education e.t.c while am able to extract the links.Any suggestions on how to extract the following info like Accounting,Adult Continuing Education e.t.c ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the value between the tags eg Accounting:

`<OPTION VALUE="descriptions/page001.html">Accounting</OPTION>`

You need `->nodeValue`

```
...
$options = $document->getElementsByTagName('option');

foreach ($options as $option) {
  storeLink($option->getAttribute('value'), $option->nodeValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.You are a legend. You just made my day !! Really appreciate the help !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
$html = '<HTML>
  <HEAD></HEAD>
  <BODY>
  <FORM ACTION="#">
  <SELECT ONCHANGE="MM_jumpMenu(\'parent\',this,0)" NAME="menu1"> 
  <OPTION VALUE="../index.html" SELECTED="SELECTED"></OPTION> 
  <OPTION VALUE="descriptions/page001.html">Accounting</OPTION> 
  <OPTION VALUE="descriptions/page122.html">Adult Continuing Education</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE="descriptions/page115.html">Energy Engineering</OPTION> 
  </SELECT>
  </P></FORM> 
  </BODY>
  </HTML>';

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$options = $document->getElementsByTagName('option');

foreach ($options as $option) {
  echo $option->getAttribute('value');
  echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for the solution but I was more interested in extracting information like Accounting,Adult Continuing Education e.t.c . I was able to scrape the URLS already with the sample script I had above.

Comment: Use $option->nodeValue instead of get attribute.